# Sequence of Functions with Changing Domain

Tags: calculus

In my calculus class we dealt with functions sequences like for example $f_n:\mathbb R\rightarrow\mathbb R$ with $f_n(x) = x^{n}$, for $n\in\mathbb N$.

But what if my function sequence is given by $f_n:\mathbb R^n\rightarrow\mathbb R$ with $f_n(x) = \sum_{i=1}^nx_i$. Does this (the $n$ now affecting the domain) change anything regarding convergence?

Comment: when talking about convergence of a sequence of functions, all of them must have the same domain for the definition to make sense.

Comment: As long as you make clear what kind of "convergence" you've put on the set of all the sets of pairs $f$ for which there is some $n$ such that $f$ is a function $\Bbb R^n\to \Bbb R$, comparatively few things may change; and by *comparatively few* I mean that everything could change, but it may still make sense. My guess is, though, that this was not quite a central aspect of your speculation, so it is very likely not to be the case.

Comment: What are the $x_i$'s?

Comment: The second function in your examples doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @WilliamElliot $x = (x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n)$. This is a quite standard notation, isn't it?